# Forms to change state when active class applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tab box and I have 3 forms in the tabs.

on page load the first form or tab should be active.

```
 <ul id="myForm" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#form1" data-toggle="tab">Form1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#form2" data-toggle="tab">Form2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#form3" data-toggle="tab">Form3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

With JS the active class switches between each link with no problem.

I am doing that like this,

```
<script>
$('#myForm a').click(function (e) {
    var tab = $(this);
    if(tab.parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(".tab-pane").removeClass('active');
            tab.parent('li').removeClass('active');
        },1);
    }
});
</script>
```

In order to keep all the forms hidden I have my css like this,

```
#form1 {
    display: none;
}

#form1 .active {
    display: block;
}

#form2 {
    display: none;
}

#form2 .active {
    display: block;
}

#form3 {
    display: none;
}

#form3 .active {
    display: block;
}
```

I believe the problem is the active link is switching to each li tag but never to the `#form1 #form2 #form3` `ID` So the tab boxes just stay blank.

What is a reasonable way to fix this?

You can see this problem [Here](http://www.wuno.com/project)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use addClass in your code instead you're using removeClass again:

```
$('#myForm a').click(function (e) {
    var tab = $(this);
    if(tab.parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(".tab-pane").removeClass('active');
            tab.parent('li').addClass('active'); //instead of removeClass
        },1);
    }
});
```

---

Also, your css is incorrect:

Instead of like below:

```
#form3 .active {
    display: block;
}
```

Use like below:

```
.active #form3 {
    display: block;
}
```

Please check your html markup to confirm.

Comment: Thanks but still same problem persist. The way I had it I can watch the class moving up and down to each link as a click it with inspect element.... But nothing loads into the tabs

Comment: I changed it all the way you said. The `active` tag just switches to each `li` as expected but nothing displays.

Comment: As my net is so slow today, I cannot check the fiddle, I'll try to help you tomorrow...

Comment: Ok thank you a ton. I have been up all night trying to fix this lol. Thats a link to the site im working on.